# Restricting textbox input to numbers in C#

Tags: c#

I want to restrict a textbox to accept only numbers in C#. How do I do that?

Comment: HTML? Windows Forms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: If C# related, maybe could be a stupid suggestion, but evaluate the NumericUpDown control if suitable.

Answer (score 16):

The most crude down and dirty way of doing it is doing something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
    }

}
```

You're still not safe with this approach, as users can still copy and paste non-numeric characters into the textbox. You still need to validate your data regardless.

Comment: users cannot remove characters either.

Comment: @LucasB, unless they cut. :)

Comment: This works great, the only change I would recommend is to enable the Backspace char as well:

Comment: This works great, the only change I would recommend is to enable the Backspace char as well:

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar==8);
    }

Answer (score 4):

From others have said before me, we have to almost know what you will use this in, WinForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight ...

But now I take a chance that it is WinForm:)

```
private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+"))
          e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for backspace

Comment: It was not what was asked here either. But if you need it.. If (e.KeyChar= vbKeyBack)  {return;}

Answer (score 2):

has some bugs but easy way :D

```
 private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            char[] originalText = textbox1.Text.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char c in originalText)
            {
                if (!(Char.IsNumber(c)))
                {
                    textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Remove(textbox1.Text.IndexOf(c));
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                    lblError.Visible = false;
            }
            textbox1.Select(textbox1.Text.Length, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the MaskedTextBox control in WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at something like this

[Masked C# TextBox Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/maskedcsedit.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way, but works ok for WPF TextBox...

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string originalText = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Trim();
        if (originalText.Length>0)
        {
            int inputOffset = e.Changes.ElementAt(0).Offset;
            char inputChar = originalText.ElementAt(inputOffset);
            if (!char.IsDigit(inputChar))
            {
                ((TextBox)sender).Text = originalText.Remove(inputOffset, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FilterTextBox](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) of AJAX Control Toolkit. Using this you can allow/disallow any character type. This is quite flexible.

Comment: Why should one take external tools, for things that can be done with builtins?

Comment: If he talks about the Web here, so just make a javascript function in an ordinary TextBox, so that it is only possible to enter the number. Then of course it checked up on the server side in retrospect. For the client side will never be safe. Since you can send the request with the same headers. And I do not see any advantage of using ajax here ...

Comment: The advantage is the simplicity of just dropping a control on the page and forgetting about it, especially if you're using the Ajax Control Toolkit already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric is numeric function. Just add the reference Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender,
        System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    if (!Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(textBox1.Text)) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    } else {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

This allows the user to enter scientific notation which is not trivial to filter for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but it works for me, running it on the TextChanged event TextBox has:

```
    private void CoordinateValidation(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        TextBox inputBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        inputBox.TextChanged -= CoordinateValidation;
        int caretPos = inputBox.CaretIndex;
        foreach (TextChange change in e.Changes) {
            if (inputBox.Text.Substring(change.Offset, change.AddedLength).Any(c => !ValidChars.Contains(c)) ||
                inputBox.Text.Count(c => c == '.') > 1 ||
                (inputBox.Text.Length > 0 && inputBox.Text.Substring(1).Contains('-'))) {
                inputBox.Text = inputBox.Text.Remove(change.Offset, change.AddedLength);
                caretPos -= change.AddedLength;
            }
        }
        inputBox.CaretIndex = caretPos;
        inputBox.TextChanged += CoordinateValidation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below code

```
private void txtbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        const char Delete = (char)8;
        e.Handled = !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != Delete;
    }
```

This will be helpful but users can Copy and Paste characters :-)