# How can i limit the textbox in visual studio ,to only input numbers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have created a calculator using Visual Studio ( C#). But i can enter abcd in the text box which displays the input and output of the calculator. I want to place a check in the properties of the textbox which only allows it to enter numbers.this is where i need help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be more specific, in order to get some help. You have created a textbox. This is ok. Using which technology? WPF, Windows Forms, ASP.NET...

Comment: In addition to Christos' comment: I bet there are already answers for any GUI technology here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting textbox input to numbers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935219/restricting-textbox-input-to-numbers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox`. The example on the MSDN site is a perfect direction to solve you problem:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is too Simple

```
private void txtNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (txtNum.Text.Length > 0)
       {
            try
            {
                Convert.ToDecimal(txtNum.Text);                  
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                txtNum.Text = txtNum.Text.Remove(txtNum.TextLength - 1, 1);
                txtNum.SelectionStart = txtNum.Text.Length; 
                txtNum.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
        }
}
```